# Java - Google App Engine - Sort ArrayList<Object> without using Collections.sort()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sorting, collections, arraylist

I need to sort an ArrayList and i can't use Collections.sort(), because Google App Engine's Java runtime environment doesn't support it. How can I do? Thanks! ^^

Comment: Does your ArrayList has duplicate values, which you want to preserve..?

Comment: No, there aren't duplicate values!

Comment: Does it support Arrays class ?

Comment: Thank you guys, i mashed up all of your suggestions and solved my issue!

Comment: Wait, really?  It doesn't support `Collections.sort()`?  That seems...odd.

Comment: Collections.sort in Java 1.7 uses the new TimSort which throws an exception if your Comparator does not follow the sort invariants (antisymmetric and transitive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ArrayList has NO DUPLICATE VALUES..... and i am assuming even if it had, you didnt wanted to have redundant data..so its better to use TreeSet and Comparator together...

Eg:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> arr = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

TreeSet<MyObject> t = new TreeSet<MyObject>(Comparator c);

t.addAll(arr);
```

Comment: Got mine totally working........And moreover the above snippet is just an example, basic idea of how to implement it.........

Answer (score 1):

Does Google App Engine support `TreeSet`? If so, assuming there are no duplicates and the elements are `Comparable`, use a `TreeSet`.

```
List list = your ArrayList
List sortedList = new ArrayList(new TreeSet(list));
```

You can also supply a `Comparator` to `TreeSet` if the elements aren't `Comparable`. I left generics left out for simplicity.

Comment: TreeSet is supported, but I need to use a custom Comparator, is this affordable with TreeSet?